# Applying function after Conditional Group By in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

This is a simplified version of my problem:
given this dataset

```
| link | category |
| ---- | -------- |
|  1   |     0    |
|  1   |     0    |
|  1   |     1    |
|  2   |     0    |
|  3   |     1    |
|  3   |     1    |
```

I would like to obtain the following:

```
| link | category counts |
| ---- | --------------- |
|  1   |      0 : 2      |
|      |      1 : 1      |
| ---- | --------------- |
|  3   |      0 : 0      |
|      |      1 : 2      |
```

Basically, i need to group data by `link`, then if the link occurs more than once, i need to apply the `value_counts` function to `category`, such as each level is displayed (e.g. for link n° 3 both levels of category are displayed, even if category 0 never occurs).

My original problem refers to a bigger dataset with many more links and categories, but solving this simplified version should help me a lot.

Here is the code for generating the simplified dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'link' : [1,1,1,2,3,3],
               'category' : [0,0,1,0,1,1]})
df
```

So far I used different strategies to reach my goal without success.
The closest one seems to be this:

```
df.groupby('link')['category'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

That gives the following:

```
| link | category counts |
| ---- | --------------- |
|  1   |      0 : 2      |
|      |      1 : 1      |
| ---- | --------------- |
|  2   |      0 : 1      |
| ---- | --------------- |
|  3   |      1 : 2      |
```

Here two issues are visible: The row with link n° 2 shouldn't be displayed, and category 0 for link n° 3 should be present, even if its count is zero.

Thanks to all those who will try to help me.

Angel

Comment: Do you want to get the data in column `category counts` into the format as shown or was is just for clarifying the problem?

Comment: it was just for clarifying the problem, just 3 columns (link, category, counts) would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
(pd.crosstab(df['link'], df['category'])
   .reindex(columns=[0, 1], fill_value=0) # safer in case no link has 1 
   .stack().reset_index(name='counts')
)
```

output:

```
   link  category  counts
0     1         0       2
1     1         1       1
2     2         0       1
3     2         1       0
4     3         0       0
5     3         1       2
```

To keep only the ids with at least one `1`:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['link'], df['category'])
   .reindex(columns=[0, 1], fill_value=0)
   .loc[lambda d: d[1].gt(0)]
   .stack().reset_index(name='counts')
)
```

output:

```
   link  category  counts
0     1         0       2
1     1         1       1
2     3         0       0
3     3         1       2
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it

```
df.groupby(['link', 'category'])['category'].agg(count='count').reset_index()
```

```
    link    category    count
0      1           0        2
1      1           1        1
2      2           0        1
3      3           1        2
```